# JavaScript Refactoring / Avoid Repitition

Tags: javascript, jquery, coding-style

I need to refactor this to avoid code repetition.

```
$('#showmore-towns').toggle(
    function() {
        $('.popularTownsAdditional').show();
        console.log(this);
        $('#showmore-town .showless').show();
        $('#showmore-town .showmore').hide();
        $('#showmore-town').removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
        return false;
    },
    function() {
        $('.popularTownsAdditional').hide();
        $('.showless').hide();
        $('.showmore').show();
        $('#showmore-towns').addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
    });

$('#showmore-cities').toggle(
    function() {
        $('.popularCitiesAdditional').show();
        $('#showmore-cities .showless').show();
        $('#showmore-cities .showmore').hide();
        $('#showmore-cities').removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
        return false;
    },
    function() {
        $('.popularCitiesAdditional').hide();
        $('#showmore-cities .showless').hide();
        $('#showmore-cities .showmore').show();
        $('#showmore-cities').addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
    });
```

basically, it shows the same functionality but only on different divs with different IDs.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably just need to reference a named function or two instead of the anon ones.

```
function showStuff(typeToShow) {
    $('.popular' + typeToShow + 'Additional').show();
    $('#showmore-' + typeToShow + .showless').show();
    $('#showmore-' + typeToShow + .showmore').hide();
    $('#showmore-' + typeToShow).removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
    return false;
}

function hideStuff(typeToHide) {
    $('.popular' + typeToHide + 'Additional').hide();
    $('#showmore-' + typeToHide + .showless').hide();
    $('#showmore-' + typeToHide + .showmore').show();
    $('#showmore-' + typeToHide ).addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
}
```

NOTE: a) You could probably make these methods a bit slicker, but you get the idea!
NOTE: b) You'd need to rename '#showmore-town' to '#showmore-towns' (with an S) if you want to use the substitution suggested.

Then in your toggle you could reference these functions:

```
$('#showmore-towns').toggle(showStuff(towns),
hideStuff(towns));

$('#showmore-cities').toggle(showStuff(cities),
hideStuff(cities));
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean...if it's always going to start with `#showmore-`...we can work it down

```
$('[id^=showmore-]').toggle(
function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    id = id.split('-')[1];
    var upperID = id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + id.slice(1);
    $('.popular'+upperID+'Additional').show();
    $('#showmore-'+id+' .showless').show();
    $('#showmore-'+id+'.showmore').hide();
    $('#showmore-'+id).removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
    return false;
},
function() {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    id = id.split('-')[1];
    var upperID = id.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + id.slice(1);
    $('.popular'+upperID+'Additional').hide();
    $('#showmore-'+id+' .showless').hide();
    $('#showmore-'+id+' .showmore').show();
    $('#showmore-'+id).addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
(function() {

    $('#showmore-towns').toggle(
        function() { showmorelessOn('#showmore-town'); },
        function() { showmorelessOff('#showmore-town'); }
    );
    $('#showmore-cities').toggle(
        function() { showmorelessOn('#showmore-town'); },
        function() { showmorelessOff('#showmore-town'); }
    );

    var showmorelessOn = function(context) {
        $('.popularCitiesAdditional').show();
        $('.showless', context).show();
        $('.showmore', context).hide();
        $(context).removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
        return false;
    };
    var showmorelessOff = function(context) {
        $('.popularCitiesAdditional').hide();
        $('.showless', context).hide();
        $('.showmore', context).show();
        $(context).addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
    };

})();
```

though I agree, could perhaps be better served on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I would do this almost entirely in the CSS.  Only use `.toggleClass()` and determine what is shown and what is hidden in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {

    $('#showmore-towns').toggle(
        function() { showmorelessOn.call($('#showmore-town')); },
        function() { showmorelessOff.call($('#showmore-town')); }
    );
    $('#showmore-cities').toggle(
        function() { showmorelessOn.call($('#showmore-town')); },
        function() { showmorelessOff.call($('#showmore-town')); }
    );

    var showmorelessOn = function() {
        $('.popularCitiesAdditional').show();
        $('.showless', this).show();
        $('.showmore', this).hide();
        $(this).removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
        return false;
    };
    var showmorelessOff = function() {
        $('.popularCitiesAdditional').hide();
        $('.showless', this).hide();
        $('.showmore', this).show();
        $(this).addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
    };

})();



(function() {

    $('#showmore-towns').toggle(
        function() { showmoreless(); }
    );
    $('#showmore-cities').toggle(
        function() { showmoreless(); }
    );

    var showmoreless = function() {
           if(this.hasClass('sd-dark28'){
            $('.popularCitiesAdditional').show();
            $('.showless', this).show();
            $('.showmore', this).hide();
            $(this).removeClass('sd-dark28').addClass('sd-dark28down');
       }
     else
       {
      $('.popularCitiesAdditional').hide();
            $('.showless', this).hide();
            $('.showmore', this).show();
            $(this).addClass('sd-dark28').removeClass('sd-dark28down');
      }
}.bind($('#showmore-town'));
})();
```